# Is it possible port forwarding with spring cloud starter zuul?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

In respect of spring cloud starter zuul we could route request path by following configuration:

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 80
zuul:
  routes:
    amqp:
      url: http://127.0.0.1:8010/amqp
    astm:
      url: http://127.0.0.1:8011/astm
    mllp:
      url: http://127.0.0.1:8012/mllp
    labs:
      url: http://127.0.0.1:8013/labs
```

Using this configuration request from **http://127.0.0.1/mllp** routed to **http://127.0.0.1:8012/mllp**. But I would like to use it for port-forwarding, Is it possible? lets say for :

```
============================================
  request                 forwarded
tcp ip:port              tcp ip:port
============================================
0.0.0.0:22210            192.168.0.10:22210
0.0.0.0:55510            192.168.0.11:55510
============================================
```

If possible how to configure it? Or any easy mechanism in spring boot application for port-forwarding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean as some kind of HAProxy replacement which runs service agnostic? Then the answer is: no! As you can see from the [Zuul Wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki) its only purpose is to filter and route HttpRequests and HttpResponses. You'll also find out the same by checking the code of [`ZuulServlet`](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/blob/1.x/zuul-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/zuul/http/ZuulServlet.java) which just handles `HttpServletRequest`s and `HttpServletResponse`s.

Comment: I agree, zuul 1.0 is pure http traffic. zuul 2.0 is based on RxNetty, so there may be a possibility in the future.